# Setting the EFI Framebuffer's Resolution during boot

Tags: boot, grub2, framebuffer

I've got a MSI WD-60 laptop running Gentoo. It has one of those 3840x2160 screens so I've had to setup Gnome/Firefox/IntellJ to double their DPI for anything to be readable. It all works fine except for the framebuffer during boot.

I've using CONFIG_FB_EFI in my kernel, so I'm assuming the kernel is using that for its framebuffer driver. I've given grub a larger font and lower resolution using:

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1920x1080
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
GRUB_FONT="/boot/grub/fonts/DejaVuSans30.pcf"
```

Grub2 looks fine and is in 1920x1080, but after I select my Kernel, the mode switches back to native and my framebuffer text is tiny. I also tried the older `vga=795` option, but that doesn't seem to work either.

It's not that big a deal, but I do have LUKS encryption so the prompt in my initram is pretty tiny. Is there anyway to get my boot sequence to either use a larger font or higher DPI or lower resolution during bootup? Is there a kernel option or argument I'm missing that specifically for the EFI framebuffer?